# How to edit default auth path in laravel 5.*

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two domains:
`account.asu.dev` and `asu.dev`

I want to use a subdomain for auth. Something like that:
`auth.asu.dev`. In routes/web.php I have `Auth::routes();` Where I can edit the default path of auth?

Comment: Which version you are using of `laravel 5.*`?

Comment: I'm using version 5.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Add following method to your `app\Http\Controller\Auth\LoginController.php`

```
/**
 * Show the application's login form.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function showLoginForm(){
    return view('auth.login');
}
```

Step 2 : Add following route to your `routes\web.php`

```
Route::get('subdomain-group/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm');
```

You can use group to add specific route for subdomain.

---

Edited :

Enter custom routes in side group as below

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'account.asu.dev'), function() {
    //Routes
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much.